# Is sun burning my Rubber plant? Or is this something else?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-care

Looks like sun damage to me. Or is it something else?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be sun damage if its been in full, hot sun all day for a while, but otherwise, there's some kind of white insect on it, and white fluffy deposits. Check backs of leaves and woody parts, because it might be scale  insect infestation; also check the white deposits with a magnifying glass. Treat for scale/mealybug if its that - you can wipe off the fluffy white bits with a cloth, but any hard scale attached to stems will need a little rubbing alcohol on a cotton bud or a cloth to get them off. Neem oil spray also controls scale.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo. I have put it under indirect light now. Will report back if these marks appear again.

Comment: I have moved the plant to shade and the problem is gone. Thanks!